# Spring MVC set attribute to request/model/modelMap

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I use Spring MVC. I need to add attribute to request or other object. It should be message that will display on screen. For example, if I use pure Servlets I may just:

```
request.setAttribute("message", "User deleted");
```

and than on JSP page

```
<div id="message">${message}</div>
```

but  when I try to do something like this in method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/delete", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String deleteUser(@RequestParam("login") String login,
        ModelMap map, HttpServletRequest request)
```

Model object -

```
model.addAttribute("message", "User deleted");
```

Map -

```
map.put("message", "User deleted");
```

ModelMap -

```
map.put("message", "User deleted");
```

HttpServletRequest -

```
request.setAttribute("message", "User deleted");
```

nothing displays. But in my browser I see: http:// localhost : 8081 /project/index?message=User+deleted

How to solve this little problem?
Thanks for your answers

Updated:

for clear understanding I try to do this:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/delete", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String deleteUser(@RequestParam("login") String login,
        Model model) {
    dao.delete(login); // there is NO exeptions
    map.addAttribute("message", "User " + login + " deleted");
    return "redirect:" + "index";
}
```

in my JSP I also display user login this way:

```
${user.login}
```

it takes user from Session and I see it login

Comment: How are you using the request attributes? In a JSP?

Comment: What is `PATH_REDIRECT`'s value?

Comment: it is "redirect:". I think that problem is in this redirection. So how I can redirect and send message?

Comment: Yes, that changes things. See the answers below.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

With your new information, the problem is `redirect:`. When you do a redirect, you send an HTTP response with a 302 (or 301) response code with a `Location` header pointing to the new url. The browser will make a new HTTP request to that location. As such, your request attributes (and model attributes) are no longer good, they don't exist in the **new** request.

Consider use flash attributes. The `RedirectAttributes` class is the way to go. [The javadoc has a good example.](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/RedirectAttributes.html)

---

A `Model` attribute is added to the request attributes much later during request processing. You therefore won't see it directly doing this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/delete", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String deleteUser(@RequestParam("login") String login,
        ModelMap map, HttpServletRequest request)
    map.put("message", "User deleted");
    String message = (String) request.getAttribute("message"); // will return null
    ...
}
```

Just trust that it will eventually be in the request attributes and therefore available in your jsp.

Comment: Yes!! Thats it! i use attr.addFlashAttribute("message", "User deleted") of RedirectAttributes object. Thanks

Comment: I have a question. How I can do the same in pure Servlets? (without any Spring)

Comment: @OleksandrHubachov The underlying implementation uses `HttpSession` attributes. With pure Servlets you could use a `Filter` to add and remove from the `HttpSession` attributes on each request. There's an example [here](http://blog.smartkey.co.uk/2011/01/implementing-flash-scope-in-java-web-applications/).

Answer (score 8):

As you are `redirecting` to a new URL, browser is actually sending a new request to the `redirect URL`. And the request attribute `map.addAttribute("message", "User " + login + " deleted");` is not present in the new request.

You can use `RedirectAttributes` to show the `message` to the user:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/delete", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String deleteUser(@RequestParam("login") String login,
        Model model,RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
    dao.delete(login); // there is NO exeptions
    //map.addAttribute("message", "User " + login + " deleted");
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "User " + login + " deleted");
    return "redirect:" + "index";
}
```

`redirectAttributes.addAttribute` constructs request parameters out of your attributes and redirects to the desired page with the request parameters. And `addFlashAttribute` stores the attributes in a flashmap (maintained in the users session and removed once the next redirected request gets fulfilled).

Comment: unfortunately, this does not work... I do not know why. As well as last time, I see in browser http:// localhost : 8081 /project/index?message=User+ololo+deleted

Comment: try this : `<c:out value="${message}" />`

Comment: @DebojitSaikia You need to use `addFlashAttribute`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But in my case I need to call addFlashAttribute method of RedirectAttributes class

Comment: @DebojitSaikia ya it helped, but what about if I want now to delete this flashAttribute? how do I delete it? I added null on this FlashAttribute... it works but it's kinda nasty

Comment: Spring framework takes care of deleting flash attribute after completion of redirected request. So you don't have to delete it manually.

Answer (score 0):

You are redirecting it in a wrong way. instead of return "redirect:"+"index" use return "redirect:/index". redirect it to your get method. as redirectattributes are post/redirect/get attribute. try this and you will get a flash message on your screen.
instead of Model use Redirectattributes.

redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("errormsg", "errormessage");
return "redirect:/index.do";